# Gutenberg: How to change Typography selector size (editor-font-sizes) depending on block in editor?

Tags: php, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm using the Gutenberg editor-font-sizes in my theme with the following values. This control is available on both paragraphs and headings, however, the value of these sizes is obviously going to be different depending on whether the block is a paragraph or a heading.

I have styled .has-font-size-[x] correctly for both paragraphs and headings in my editor stylesheet. However, the 'size' attribute is adding an inline style which is overriding my styles. I'm unable to remove the size attribute. Obviously I don't want a small heading to be the same size as a small paragraph in the editor, so what should I do?

```
add_theme_support( 
        'editor-font-sizes',
        [
            [
                'name'  => esc_html__( 'Small', 'str' ),
                'shortName' => __( 'S', 'str' ),
                'size'      => 18,
                'slug'  => 'small',
            ],
            [
                'name'  => esc_html__( 'Medium', 'str' ),
                'shortName' => __( 'N', 'str' ),
                'size'      => 21,
                'slug'  => 'medium',
            ],
            [
                'name'  => esc_html__( 'Large', 'str' ),
                'shortName' => __( 'L', 'str' ),
                'size'      => 29,
                'slug'  => 'large',
            ],
        ]
    );
```

Comment: We're programmers, we can read. Please read about [why you shouldn’t upload images of code or errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Ok sorry, edited. Any suggestions on the issue?

Comment: I believe the class names have a naming structure like this: ´.has-(slug)-font-size´ (I am using 5.6 and no extra Gutenberg plugin installed). If you just use the select dropdown to select the custom size names in the backend, no inline styles should be added. But if you use the numerical input to add an individual font size, an inline style is created (wouldn't be possible otherwise). If you still get inline styles for whatever reason, you could overwrite them by using "!important" in your CSS rules. Bit of a bad practice though...

Comment: Documentation here: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/theme-support/#block-font-sizes

Comment: I've already assigned styles to all my .has-[x]-font-size classes, maybe that is only the case with the default dropdown and not one with custom sizes?